# xpath context nodes during axis navigation

Tags: xml, xpath

Looking at the DTD:

```
<!ELEMENT root (a|b)+>
<!ELEMENT a (a|b)*>
<!ELEMENT b (a|b)*>
```

And the following simple XML: (I tagged the elements for convenience)

```
<root>
  <b1>
    <b2></b2>
    <a1></a1>
  </b1>
  <b3></b3>
</root>
```

When I perform the following queries:

```
a) /descendant-or-self::node()/b[1]
b) /descendant-or-self::b[1]
```

Both in a) and b), before applying [1], I get all the b's in the XML tree.
But when I ask for the first b, in a) I get {b1,b2} and in b) I get only {b1}.
My question is, what's the logic about context nodes in this scenario? In other words, why is the difference between "/descendant-or-self::node()/b" (which I know equivalent to "//") and "/descendant-or-self/b"?

Answer (score 1):

`/descendant-or-self::node()/b[1]` selects all `b` elements that are the first (`[1]`) `b` child of their parent element as `/descendant-or-self::node()/b[1]` is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/child::b[1]`. `/descendant-or-self::b` selects all `b` elements in the document and with `/descendant-or-self::b[1]` you select the first of them.

Comment: In general, /descendant-or-self::b will return all the b where the context node is the "self" in where I navigate to "descendant-or-self" from? If so, so "/descendant-or-self::b[2]" I'll get the second closest tag to root in the xml file, b2 in my example?